# Comparar produtos por anos em colunas diferentes de uma mesma tabela

Tags: postgresql

Boa tarde!

Gostaria de realizar um select em sql que resolvesse a seguinte questão:
Tenho uma tabela de faturamento relacionada com uma de produtos, porém, quero comparar os resultados de um mesmo produto em 2018 e 2019.

A tabela tem mais ou menos essa estrutura:

[image: estrutura]

Gostaria de um resultado como esse:

[image: result]

Alguém poderia ajudar? Agradeço desde já! :)

Comment: Tente fazer um count  usando o between, e depois compara os count dos anos

Comment: Luiz, pode me ajudar com um exemplo? Ajudaria muito. Obrigado por responder! :)

Comment: https://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/07/simple-case-for-pivoting-in-sql/   pivot com CASE uma solução possível. A pergunra é pertinente , não entendo a crítica.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Motta. Eu também não entendi a crítica a pergunta, achei válida... rs Bola pra frente!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente:

```
SELECT coalesce(a.produto, b.produto) AS "Produto", coalesce(a.quantidade, 0) AS "Qtd 2018", coalesce(b.quantidade, 0) AS "Qtd 2019" FROM
 (SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE ano = 2018) a
 FULL OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE ano = 2019) b
 ON (a.produto = b.produto)
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Outra possibilidade é utilizar a função crosstab do módulo tablefunc (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html).

Comment: Deu certinho! Muito obrigado pela ajuda. :)